# How to insert a vector some objects in c++

Tags: c++

Hey guys I have text file like this

```
R,D,B,G,G,B,D,R,R,D,B,G,G,D,R,R,G,R,D,B
D,B,B,R,D,R,D,G,B,G,D,B,G,R,B,G,B,B,D,D
```

and I want to read from file and create objects finaly i want to insert a vektor but

i have ***ld returned 1 exit status error***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class  Base {
public:
    enum result{
        Kaybetbek=0,
        Beraberlik=1,
        Kazanmak=2
    };

    virtual void compare(Base *) const ;
    virtual void print();
};

class Green:public Base{
public:
    void compare( Base * ) {

    };
    void print(){
        cout<<"G";
    }

};
//Blue class
class Blue:public Base{
public:
    void compare( Base * ) {

    }
    void print(){
        cout<<"B";
    }
};
//Red class
class Red:public Base{
public:
    void compare( Base * ) {

    }
    void print(){
        cout<<"R";
    }

};
class Dark_Red:public Red{
public:
    void compare( Base * ) {

    }
    void print(){
        cout<<"D";
    }

};
void display(){

}
int main(){
ifstream file ;
string s;
Base* p1;
Base* p2;
vector<Base*> player1;
vector<Base*> player2;
vector<Base>::iterator ptr1;
vector<Base>::iterator ptr2;

file.open("/home/elbibi/CLionProjects/untitled2/Kartlar.txt");
if(file.is_open()){
    while(getline(file,s)){
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size();i++) {
            if (s[i]=='R'){
                Red* red;
                player1[i]=red;
            }
            if (s[i]=='D'){
                Dark_Red* darkred;
                player1[i]=darkred;
            }
            if (s[i]=='B'){
                Blue *blue;
                player1[i]=blue;
            }
            if (s[i]=='G'){
                Green *green;
                player1[i]=green;
            }
        }

    }
}
else{ cout<< "File not found";}
for (auto x :player1) {
   x->print();
}
    return 0;
}
```

The Error:

```
====================[ Build | untitled2 | Debug ]===============================
/opt/clion/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/elbibi/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug --target untitled2 -- -j 2
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable untitled2
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/home/elbibi/CLionProjects/untitled2/main.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Base::print()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `Base::Base(Base const&)':
/home/elbibi/CLionProjects/untitled2/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `vtable for Base'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/build.make:84: untitled2] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: untitled2] Error 2***

<pre>
```

Comment: When you ask questions about build errors (the all `ld` errors are build errors) then please include the actual errors you get, in full and complete, copy-pasted as text into the question. Also please read [the editing and formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format your posts properly. Lastly please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: There's also plenty of other problems in your code, besides the build error, things that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and probable crashes.

Comment: I got it, but my compiler retured me turkish output ppl can't understand

Comment: For assistance, search the internet for "read file c++ CSV".  Your input file is "CSV" or Comma Separated Values.

Comment: You can always change your OS regional language to English, temporary, to get messages in English. Or use a translation-service. However, it's easy to guess about your errors: It probably states something about a missing vtable or similar, and you get it because all classes *must* implement non-abstract virtual member functions.

Comment: ok thanks but now  how can i update post :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some severe bugs in your which will have a fatal impact. Example:

```
Red* red;
player1[i]=red;
```

Variable "red" is defined, but not initialzed. So pointing to nowhere. Dereferencing this point will be later a desaster. Then you assign to "player[i]". But the "player"-vector is empty. So, you cannot access the "[i]"-th element of player. It does not yet exist. Either you use a constructor for the vector to reserve space, or, you should use the `push_back` function of the vector. This would work.

You should not use "new" or "raw" pointers for owned memory in C++. Too dangerous. Please use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Then, overall you made a typical use case for the so called "abstract factory pattern". You read a value, and, depending on that, you create a (from a base class) derived class. Then you put that in a `std::vector` with base class pointers (`std::unique_ptr<Base>`).

Then you call the overwritten "print" function with the base class pointer.

In the below example I build a tiny factory for you, to accomplish your needs. Additionally I use modern C++ algorithms to fulfil the tasks.

Please study. Maybe, it can give you an idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

// Class hierachy
class  Base {
public:
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};
class Green : public Base {
public:
    void print() const override { std::cout << "G"; }
};
class Blue : public Base {
public:
    void print() const override { std::cout << "B"; }
};
class Red : public Base {
public:
    void print() const override { std::cout << "R"; }
};
class DarkRed : public Red {
public:
    void print() const override { std::cout << "D"; }
};

// Make writing easier
using BasePtr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

// Factory functions
std::unique_ptr<Base> makeGreen()   { return std::make_unique<Green>(); }
std::unique_ptr<Base> makeBlue()    { return std::make_unique<Blue>(); }
std::unique_ptr<Base> makeRed()     { return std::make_unique<Red>(); }
std::unique_ptr<Base> makeDarkRed() { return std::make_unique<DarkRed>(); }

// Factory 
std::map<std::string, std::function<BasePtr()>> factory {
    {"G",makeGreen},
    {"B",makeBlue},
    {"R",makeRed},
    {"D",makeDarkRed}
};

// Name of source file. Please adapt
const std::string sourceFileName("r:\\Kartlar.txt");
const std::regex re{ R"(([GBRD]))" };

using Cards = std::vector<BasePtr>;
using Player = std::vector<Cards>;

int main(void) {
    // The vector with pointers to base class
    Player player{};

    if (std::ifstream ifs(sourceFileName); ifs) {
        // Read all lines of the source files and assign to cards to players
        for (std::string line{}; std::getline(ifs, line);) {

            // Here we will store all cards
            Cards cards{};
            // For all letters (GBRD) in the string
            std::for_each(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, 1), {},
                // call factory function and add to cards
                [&](const std::string & s) {cards.emplace_back(factory[s]()); });

            // Add all read cards to player
            player.push_back(std::move(cards));
        }

        // For each player, print all cards
        for (const Cards& cards : player) {
            for (const BasePtr& basePtr : cards) {
                basePtr->print();
                std::cout << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
}
```

Please note. I did not add to much error checking . . .